# Effects of chmod 777 /. -R with root

Tags: linux, ssh, root, chmod

So one of my colleges just did the above to try and fix some permission issues I got him to ctrl-C it quite quickly. The server seams to be ok but im worried.

What would the effect of "/." be, equivalent to "/"?

Any way to fix essential server permission that are now 777?

Comment: This probably does not belong here. Try serverfault.com or unix.stackexchange.com. =)

Comment: Beware the setuid, setgid and sticky bits!

Comment: "one of my colleagues" ... hahaha.  Classic example of "so I have this "friend" that [insert massive embarassing screw up here]. How do I help "him" fix it." Made my day.

Comment: Hi Ben, glad this made you laugh, I certainly wasn't finding it funny.  This has happened 2 times in the  4 Years I've been with my current company.  We had to scrap the server both times.  It was a different "Colleague" the second time, but unfortunately I again had to clean up the mess.  This time I was in a position to stop it happening again and early last year I made some changes to policy to ensure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every directory in Linux contains the two special directory names "." and "..".  The ".." meaning "up-one" in the directory tree and the "." meaning the current node in the tree.  This includes the root ("/") directory:

```
$ ls -la /
total 472
drwxr-xr-x  29 root root   4096 Nov 22 13:03 .
drwxr-xr-x  29 root root   4096 Nov 22 13:03 ..
```

So executing a command on the directory "/." is really saying "execute this command on the '.' directory inside of '/'", which is just the root itself.

As far as fixing the original permissions... I hope you've made system backups :)

Answer (score 1):

The effect will be the same, so depending on how quick you where to stop this (and how fast your server is) there will be files (and directories!) with incorrect permissions. You should be able to use the find command (the -perm option) to find all files which now have the 777 permission.

If you have a backup system which properly retains permissions you could probably find a way to script the old permissions back if to many files are changed to do it manually. But without a backup there isn't much left but to run to the list of files with 777 permissions and fix them manually.